# Why is continue not working?

Tags: python

In my quest to figure out `continue` I wanted to write a simple loop that included both `break` and `continue`. I understand that `break` ends the loop, but I can't figure out why `print('Why won't this ever print!')` is never triggered.

```
In [21]: 
import random

while True:
    n = random.randint(0,5)
    if n == 5:
        print('It is 5!')
        break
    else:
        print('It is not 5!')
        continue
    print('Why won't this ever print!')

Out [21]:
It is not 5!
It is not 5!
It is 5!
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Because that's the exact purpose of `continue` - move to the next loop iteration, skipping any subsequent statements.

Comment: I thought break ends the loop (thus skipping all subsequent steps).

Comment: `break` exist the loop entirely.  `continue` stays in the loop but moves to the next iteration.

Answer (score 9):

[continue](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) returns the flow of execution back to the top of the loop for another iteration. It does not continue the same iteration the loop.

If you were to *remove* the `continue` statement, then Python *would* proceed to the next statment, and print `'Why won't this ever print!`.

Answer (score 5):

`break` breaks out of the loop. `continue` starts back over at the beginning *without finishing the current iteration*. You don't have any branch that will ever reach that `print` statement.

Comment: So break halts the entire thing while continue restarts it back at the top?

Comment: @Anton Yes, `break` stops the loop entirely and your program will continue on with the first statement after the loop. `continue` skips the remainder of the body of the loop and starts it back over from the top at the next iteration.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to understand `continue` and `break` is to visualize it this way.

[image]

- When `continue` is triggered, it will take you back to loop-condition, if condition is met, it do everything inside the loop again, if condition is not met, it will skip out of the loop.
- When `break` is triggered, it immediately takes you out of the loop.

Answer (score 2):

continue is used to get out of the current iteration of the loop and move into the next iteration. So if you print "continue", the print statement gets skipped.

Answer (score 1):

`continue` stops current loop iteration and starts the next one, so your line **shouldn't** be executed.

Answer (score 0):

It won't print, because it is never reached. You either `break` or `continue` before.

Answer (score 0):

After the `continue` statement, the flow of your program starts at the beginning of the `while` loop again.

From the docs:

The continue statement, also borrowed from C, continues with the next iteration of the loop

Reference:

http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html